# could not find declaration file for 'merge-graphql-schemas' TYPESCRIPT

Tags: typescript, graphql

I am unable to compile typescript unless I remove noImplicitAny

And I get this error, I am using the merge-graphql-schemas lib from npm

```
    TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/utils/genSchema.ts(1,44): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'merge-graphql-schemas'. '/home/user/Documents/voting/node_modules/merge-graphql-schemas/dist/index.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/merge-graphql-schemas` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'merge-graphql-schemas';
```

In my 
src->types->merge-graphql-schemas.d.ts

declare module "merge-graphql-schemas";

my tsconfig is like this

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",

    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Should I specifically do something?
I changed the lib to schemaglue from npm and even that also does not have types so I did the same thing, still I get the same error for schemaglue.
Maybe I am missing something in tsconfig?

this is why I used merge-schema-graphql

```
    import { mergeTypes, mergeResolvers } from "merge-graphql-schemas";
import * as path from "path";
import * as fs from "fs";
import { makeExecutableSchema } from "graphql-tools";
import * as glob from "glob";

export const genSchema = () => {
  const pathToModules = path.join(__dirname, "../modules");
  const graphqlTypes = glob
    .sync(`${pathToModules}/**/*.graphql`)
    .map(x => fs.readFileSync(x, { encoding: "utf8" }));

  const resolvers = glob
    .sync(`${pathToModules}/**/resolvers.?s`)
    .map(resolver => require(resolver).resolvers);

  return makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: mergeTypes(graphqlTypes),
    resolvers: mergeResolvers(resolvers)
  });
};
```

courtesy Youtube Benawad graphql-ts-server-boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue!
I fixed it by moving

```
import { fileLoader, mergeTypes, mergeResolvers } from 'merge-graphql-schemas'
```

to after

```
import { graphqlExpress, graphiqlExpress } from 'apollo-server-express'
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools'
```

I'm not entirely sure why this happens, but I believe it is due to some wonky dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue: https://github.com/okgrow/merge-graphql-schemas/issues/154

For simple, you can create a `global.d.ts` file and put these declaration:

```
declare module 'merge-graphql-schemas' {
  export function fileLoader(...args: any[]): any;
  export function mergeResolvers(...args: any[]): any;
  export function mergeTypes(...args: any[]): any;
}
```